# Is there such a thing as "too much detail" in worldbuilding?

Tags: worldbuilding-process

I'm currently working on my own world and something I always wonder when worldbuilding is if I'm putting in "too much detail".
One of my favourite parts (and one of the most important in general) of worldbuilding is details. Sometimes, however, it seems like I'm putting in "too much" detail.

For example, I may get carried away with a very specific aspect of my world (such as a fictional brand or company) and add very specific details to it, like products or services that have little to no significance.

Is this truly a thing? If so, is there a threshold or a certain point where the amount of detail is "too much"? Is it better to be more vague or more specific?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is a book that I really like, called "Blindsight", by Peter Watts which, in my opinion, illustrates this issue perfectly. In my opinion, this book is the prime example of both too much detail in worldbuilding and too little at the same time. It is hard to communicate what it means precisely, this why I am writing a comment, not an answer

Comment: Since this isn't actually asking for help with worldbuilding I think it's actually more on topic for the writing site then this one despite it's asking about worldbuilding.

Comment: From a writing perspective, it's a bit foolish to commit yourself to details that have nothing to do with your plot. You might regret it later.

Comment: fwiw, i like how Skyrim included books on various topics. Have you considered anything along those lines? Whether that is a thing or could potentially be a thing is a question again of how fruitful it is and of course how you reach the bottom line.

Comment: I think it's not about how much detail, but about how those details are presented in the story. There are really great novels that contain a ton of details about their worldbuilding; and there are really great novels with barely any details at all on the worldbuilding; and there are also novels that feel like they have too many details because those details are presented to the reader in a manner that looks boring or offtopic; and there are also novels that feel like they don't have enough details and everything feels blurry. It's not about the quantity, it's about the way it's presented.

Comment: I'd say it depends on how much is actually important to the story in the end.

Comment: That's why you should find a writer's group or something similar to reflect ideas off of. I guess this website is a good start

Comment: Related:  https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1427/why-is-there-so-much-technical-detail-of-whaling-included-in-moby-dick

Comment: i think there's kind of a ratio, say if you're making a 100 page worth of story, but then you make 2000 pages of reference , I think that's an over, but where's the sweet / rationally sound ratio is up to the writer, but there's definitely a line where there is definitely too much detail

Comment: There's no way to measure this. It's opinion-based even if you specified what the worldbuilding is for (game, novel, etc).

Answer (score 18):

It's not really possible to answer whether there is such a thing as too much detail.  Such a question is very much opinion based.  However, we can answer some related questions about what signs might one see that suggests that one has gone into too much detail.

The obvious answer is, of course, time.  If you're spending all your time worldbuilding, you're not spending that time doing other things.  If other aspects of your game/story/etc. are suffering due to lack of time, that may be a sign that you need to cut back on worldbuilding.

Another warning sign is when the reader/player/etc. is *obliged* to join you on your worldbuilding journey.  Take Tolkien's languages, for instance.  He put a *tremendous* amount of worldbuilding effort into his languages for the Lord of the Rings series of books.  If you want, you can find the etymology for many words in Quenya, tracing how they morphed over hundreds of thousands of years.  But Tolkien doesn't drag you through any of that (well, at least he doesn't outside of the The Silmarillion).   You aren't obliged to understand cognates of a word between Quenya and Sindarin in order to solve a murder mystery.  They merely bring flavor.  If you find the need to drag the reader/player/etc. along with you to show off the details, it's probably time to stop.

Too much detail can also breed disbelief.  The smaller the detail the more it needs to flow on its own from the world around it.  If you have to "nudge" some major motif a bit to fit with the story, that may be part of worldbuilding.  However, if you try to apply the same nudge to a bunch of tiny details, they start to feel exactly like that: an author trying to fudge the details to make a story.

In the same vein, too much detail can trap your plot.  Sometimes a writer does need to nudge things one way or another.  If you haven't specified too much detail, that nudging can shape the larger world motifs.  But if you've already specified all the details, then the nudging can only bludgeon some poor hapless details.  An interesting example of this shows up in The Martian with the sand storm.  Andy Weir fills the book with fine details, building a wonderful world.  But anyone who knows astronomy will quickly pick up on the fact that such a dust storm could never occur.  The Martian atmosphere is too thin to carry such particles.  Weir had to [admit](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt3659388/goofs/) that the sandstorm was manufactured to start the story off, taking creative license to create the requisite conflict, and that it was a great scientific inaccuracy in an otherwise science-detail full world.

Comment: I find it ironic you site Tolken as an example of worldbuilding not being forced on someone, because if anything I feel he threw too much worldbuilding at his audience.  Yes when it comes to languages it wasn't forced on you, but so much about his world was tossed at you, with you expected to remember his million fictional names and be able to figure out what is going on.  For instance who is Tom Bombadil?  do you know from just reading the Fellowship of the Ring?

Comment: In that case Tom had a backstory and plenty of stuff that made sense to Tolken, but to an audience reading just the book he shows up in he is implied to be important, built up as a  mystery, and then forgotten unless the audience goes and hunts down outside information.  That's one random example, but it shows' up all over the place.  Tolkien loved his world so much he kept dropping hints that weren't fully elaborated on and frankly I believe distracted from the story as a whole.

Comment: @dsollen Some readers prefer the feeling of a tightly plotted world where everything matters and is directly relevant.  Some readers prefer a world that feels much bigger than the present story.  At a certain point it isn't "the author should have done it according to my tastes" so much as just "it wasn't to my tastes."

Comment: @dsollen I thoroughly enjoyed The Hobbit and LoTR (books, of course!) without memorizing everyone's genealogy. Likewise, it's irrelevant who Tom is.

Comment: Hey dol! Merry dol! What ye be criticising old Tom for? I'll sing you up a storm about how he's got less worldbuilding around him than anyone! He's an arbitrarily merry fellow. His jacket is blue, and his boots are yellow!

Answer (score 11):

If you spend your entire life world building, and never actually write things in that world, then you are doing too much world building. Maybe you're enjoying it for its own sake, in which case you shouldn't care about our opinion.

If you do care about our opinion, then you need to do something that presents your world to the rest of us. Consider yourself to be a cultural ambassador to your world. Your job, as a writer, is to find the interesting, nuanced, and just plain weird stuff that comes from your culture, and show it to us as the background of a story.

With that in mind, obsessing over the minutia of the geology of a planet probably isn't very fertile ground for finding details that fascinate your readers. Pages of exposition about some obscure detail of how your society builds its armor will drive people off before they actually get to your story. Trying to identify the specific genes in a genetic sequence that will result in photosynthetic humans is counter-productive.

Let's face it, even reading the previous list of things not to list probably turned your brain off.

Every world needs underpinned nuts and bolts to hold things together, of course. If the weird parts are pasted on without thought, you get shlock. Again, maybe you want to write shlock. Someone's gotta do it, but then the details shouldn't matter. Know your audience.

My philosophy is that I do enough world building so that my gaps in how the world works don't become red herrings that distract my readers from the stuff that's really interesting. In fact, that, in my opinion, is the essence of good Science Fiction. It's describing a solid enough understanding of the science so that the things that are fascinating stand out in stark contrast.

If you do this right, then your readers will be able to infer how your world is constructed from the events that occur, the same way we inferred the existence of Neptune from its effects on the other planets.

Answer (score 6):

A question of time and effort.

Generally speaking, you should have much more detail in your notes than you put into the published work. Say you have a science-fiction setting with many inhabited worlds, and the characters are stranded on one while they need to get the funds to buy the spare parts to repair their starship.

You define a fictional currency unit, a cost for the missing parts, the wages for people with the characters' skills, and the daily cost of living.

$$\text{days to earn wages} = \frac{\text{parts cost}}{(\text{daily wage} - \text{cost of living}) \times \text{crew size}}$$

There are plenty of factors where you can shatter "willing suspension of disbelief" if you are not careful. What is the cost to buy and operate a large starship in your setting? You could have a desert world, yet the setting is spoiled because importing bottled water is affordable by your numbers. Or you could have a near-vacuum world, yet the setting is spoiled because the cost of living in domes with recycled air exceeds the possible wages even for skilled workers. And so on.

The detailed calculations might never be revealed, but you need them **unless you plan to gloss over such detail and focus on character and plot.** It is quite possible to tell stories that way. But if you go for nuts and bolts, go deep enough.

Answer (score 4):

When you come to write, there is a step called "smother your darlings". The text should move the plot onward with a steady and uniform style. You may have some amazing fun fact about the place you are now in. But the characters present may not know the background. Or it does not help the current plot. But you really liked it.

I have just written a book on colour, and I remember weeding out the facts and the weird bits of history. I found them fascinating, and not many other people knew them, but they would just get in the way for a first-time reader. Or sometimes, you could move a fact to another place and it had a positive contribution. So "smother your darlings is real", but only for writing as far as I know.

Stick all the background detail you like. You may have to decide not to use any given fact at a later stage, but that isn't a limit in worldbuilding as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

### There is only *forcing* too much detail unto others.

No matter what you write (draw/animate/film/&c.), you should focus on the narrative. A vastness of lore and history and thoughtfulness will go a long way to ground your readers, but it is key that you only communicate it when the narrative asks for it.

Take, for example, Tolkien. The richness of his worldbuilding is awe-inspiring, and it is wonderful to read through all that content (once you are familiar with and fond of his universe). But in his major novels, he relayed parts of that information only when the plot asked for it.

However, like Aragorn singing a song of old to frame an event, locale, or other character within the lore of the world, you can have a character talk about the intricacies of a specific brand, simply because of a strange fascination, or because their family is somehow involved, or because they happened to pick it up somewhere and they remembered it (for a good, but perhaps not obvious, reason).

Answer (score 2):

It's "too much world building" when it keeps you from actually using the world.

So long as you are actually using it, it's no issue

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

Worlds in and of themselves are exactly like an insect on a pin: interesting in a scientific and sterile manner, but completely and utterly dead. It is the motivations and consequent actions of the **characters** living in that world that make it come alive, and subsequently make it interesting in a relatable way. Write those characters' story, and you'll find that in turn will tell you what to write about their world's story - and how much.

Worldbuilding is easy, and therefore fun; writing characters is difficult, and therefore often far less so. But as with most things in life, if you persevere with what is difficult, you're likely to have far more success than just sticking with what's easy.

Answer (score 1):

## No such thing as too much. Only too many at once.

Details are what makes a world come to life. This can be important to the story or as useless information as it would be in real life. What can be too much is how many details you give. This obviously differs per person per story, but you can make a guess. In the end you can give any and all details you want. As long as it isn't too much all at once. Spread it out in the story.

Comment: **Snork.** There can certainly be too much detail.  I could write a novel's worth of words describing the room in which an event takes place and never get around to describing what actually happened.  Who would read it? Nobody, 'cause their eyes would glaze over and they'd fall asleep long before I got done describing the Wimshurst machine on the cabinet, let alone the contents of the clothes cabinet.

Comment: @JRE Please adhere to reading the whole answer begore you comment. Comments are also intended to ultimately improve the answer. Take it into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

**But --**

-- this is not a problem with your worldbuilding. You could see it as more like a hint to yourself: that this thing that you tend to put so much effort into thinking about, is something that you would like to actually *do*. As in, to make it happen in the real world. If that thing is possible, legal, achievable within your circumstances, etc. - why not give it a try instead, or perhaps in addition to, writing about it?